# Handle async requests in react native / redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I'm using firebase to build an app with react native. I'm struggling with how I should structure my redux actions within my app.

As is stands I have a function that will fetch a users profile. I make a reference to the firebase firestore and then use then and catch statements to resolve the promise returned. Here is where my problem comes into it.

```
return(dispatch){
dispatch({type: GET_PROFILE})
var docRef = firebase.firestore().doc('users/' + userUid);
docRef.get()
.then(() => {
    dispatch({type: GET_PROFILE_SUCCESS})
})
.catch(() => {
   dispatch({type: GET_PROFILE_FAIL})
})
}
```

I am dispatching the action GET_PROFILE so that when my render function is called in my profile screen, it will load a spinner while the user waits. 
The problem I've got is that if the user isn't connected to the internet. When they make the request, the action is sent to redux but GET PROFILE SUCCESS / FAIL is never dispatched, as having no internet connection isn't an error

As a result all the user sees is a spinner until they restart the app. I basically want to alert the user that they need a connection to the internet.
I'm new to react native, Could someone advise me what's the best way to do this in react native?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get network informations with [NetInfo](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html) and store it in redux :

In your main component :

```
componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then((isConnected) => {
      store.dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_CONNECTION_STATUS', isConnected });
    });
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectionChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectionChange);

handleConnectionChange = (isConnected: boolean) => {
    store.dispatch({ type: 'CHANGE_CONNECTION_STATUS', isConnected }));
}
```

Then you can wrap your request with an if statement to handle offline use cases :

```
return(dispatch){
  if(store.getState().isConnected) {
    dispatch({type: GET_PROFILE})
    var docRef = firebase.firestore().doc('users/' + userUid);
    docRef.get()
    .then(() => {
        dispatch({type: GET_PROFILE_SUCCESS})
    })
    .catch(() => {
       dispatch({type: GET_PROFILE_FAIL})
    })
  } else {
    Alert.alert('You are offline');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Dyo. This looks like the way I will probably resolve this issue. I'm assuming that I can leave the listener attached throughout the lifetime of the user session? Or would I run into problems with firebase if I didn't unmount it?  Thanks

Comment: I don't know what's happening if you don't remove the listener when unmounting but i think you should. There will be no probleme with firebase but your `isConnected`state could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code for network fail condition

```
return(dispatch){
    dispatch({type: GET_PROFILE})
    var docRef = firebase.firestore().doc('users/' + userUid);
    docRef.get()
    .then(() => {
        dispatch({type: GET_PROFILE_SUCCESS})
    }, 
      // ADD THESE LINES
      (error) => {
            dispatch({type: GET_PROFILE_FAIL})
          })
    .catch(() => {
       dispatch({type: GET_PROFILE_FAIL})
    })
    }
```

Comment: Hi Pulkit, thanks for answering. I've tried this method and it doesn't seem to work, could this be related in some way to firebase? Thanks

Comment: Please console the values in both the arguments of .then function and catch function and check at least one of them will print the value.

Comment: Hi Pulkit. Neither of the functions are printing the values in the console when disconnected from the internet. The then function is firing properly when connected

Comment: It may take time. So you can wait for 3-4 minutes.